# Body and Footer gone on homepage and error message after clearing cache Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I recently was working on my website and decided to clear all caches and now the homepage only shows the header and nothing else. All the other pages work fine but i do get this error:

> Warning: include(page-front.php) [function.include]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 14 of
>   /home/anthonyd/public_html/graphicimpress/sites/all/themes/gi_0612/page.tpl.php).
>   Warning: include(page-front.php) [function.include]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 14 of
>   /home/anthonyd/public_html/graphicimpress/sites/all/themes/gi_0612/page.tpl.php).
>   Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'page-front.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   include() (line 14 of
>   /home/anthonyd/public_html/graphicimpress/sites/all/themes/gi_0612/page.tpl.php).

I did see a very similar problem someone else posted but it was for drupal 6 and the fix was to rebuild the modules by visiting admin/build/modules
and rebuild themes by visiting admin/build/themes. Unfortunately D7 does not have the same menu options.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file `/home/anthonyd/public_html/graphicimpress/sites/all/themes/gi_0612/page.tpl.php` on line 14, function `include('page-front.php')` trying to include file `page-front.php` into your `page.tpl.php`, but there's no such file as `page-front.php`.

Make sure that this file (`page-front.php`) exist, or remove `include('page-front.php')` from `page.tpl.php`.

Comment: ugh..it's always something so obvious isn't it?! Thanks so much for your help